# Ubuntu 16.04 - Fails to reboot

Tags: 16.04, graphics, reboot, restart

I'm having an issue where my Ubuntu system is failing to reboot.

When the restart button is clicked, the system shows the splash screen normally, but then the screen quickly deteriorates graphically to this state:

[image]

The system then reloads the desktop, as if it had restarted... additionally, it shuts down fine and restarts fine...

Any suggestions?

Let me know what other information might help fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to of fixed itself on the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10